# Spring boot app start up hibernate exception :GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring boot app. And I am connecting to `postgres` db.

Here is my properties file (`hibernate specific props`):

```
# Hibernate specific entries
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
#hibernate.format_sql=true
#hibernate.default_schema=operations
```

When I am running my app it runs fine... however in the logs i can see some **WARNINGS** *and not ERROR* like below :

**App Log:**

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : 
Error executing DDL "alter table if exists <table_name> add column role_id int4 not null" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: 
Error executing DDL "alter table if exists <table_name> add column role_id int4 not null" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]

.....

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "role_id" contains null values
```

**My table structure :**

I am using composite PK as `@Embeddable` and using that id in my entity class.

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
public class IdPK implements Serializable {
    
    private Integer roleId;
    private String  roleName;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class MyTable{
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private IdPK idpk ;

}
```

The error is logged during start up, however there is no issue with the app.

**What I have tried :**

I have tried using the annotation in both the composite PK class and the entity class but they dont have any effect. The error still persists.

```
@NonNull // lombok
@Column(name = roleid, nullable = false)
```

I want to add that I am using flyway scripts to migrate the db schemas.
I am adding my relevant table create schema as well :

```
-- Table: public.my_table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.my_table;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.my_table
(
    roleid integer NOT NULL,
    rolename character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.my_table;
```

And this is how table is actually created in the db :

```
-- Table: public.my_table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.my_table;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.my_table
(
    roleid integer NOT NULL,
    rolename character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.my_table OWNER to postgres;
```

**UPDATE:**

Table entries :

```
roleid   |   rolename
1        |   "RM"
2        |   "SM"
3        |   "DM"
```

**Observation:**

Also I did not understand this line in the error :

```
ERROR: column "role_id" contains null values
```

Where the column name is actually `roleid`  **AND NOT** `role_id`.

I have searched for this issue, and there were different solutions in `StackOverflow`, however none is able to fix this one. Can anyone help me out on this error, how to fix them. I am getting these same errors for 3 other tables with similar setup. Am I missing any particular configuration.

Comment: There seems to be data in the table where the role_id column has null values

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : Nope, No null values. I will add the table entry as well.

Comment: `Error executing DDL "alter table if exists <table_name> add column role_id int4 not null" via JDBC Statement` looks like hibernate wants to add another column without a default value. And since you already have rows in the table, it would default to null for those rows

Comment: @Som please add all the class code you have tried with the code `@Column(name = roleid, nullable = false)`